# How to run or execute two MSBuilds

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, build

I want to create one MSBuild that will execute two others..

How can i import the two others and run each of their targets in order?

**UPDATE**:

I was able to get this working with the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/MsBuild/2003">
    <Target Name="BuildAll">
        <Exec Command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe MSBuildSettings.xml" />
        <Exec Command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe PostBuild.xml" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted but it may have been because you've not specified why you are attempting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process.Start("yourFirstExecutable.exe");
Process.Start("yourSecondExecutable.exe");
```

Is that what you are looking for??  `Process.Start()` runs an external executable.

Comment: I'd guess the actual problem isn't to run an executable from c# but calling MSBuild projects in a given order from MSBuild itself.

Answer (score 1):

why not just write a batch file that executes two msbuild commands?

Comment: +1 Best solution if you don't want to fiddle with MSBuild too much.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would be done using the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) and dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="PostBuild">
    <Target Name="MainBuild">
        <MSBuild Projects="MSBuildSettings.xml" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="PostBuild" DependsOnTargets="MainBuild">
        <MSBuild Projects="PostBuild.xml" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```